# SoapUI Mock service groovey script to select right response

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have a mock service that has an operation with two possible responses. How can I select the right response based on a condition using scripting? Eg.

```
if(context.sessionID == ''){
 // use response 1 
} else {
 // use response 2
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
context.httpResponse = "response 1"
```

Answer (score 3):

If your code is in the dispatch script of the "MockResponses" then the correct syntax is:

```
return "response 1"
```

[EDIT]
This is well-explained in the official web-site:
http://www.soapui.org/Service-Mocking/creating-dynamic-mockservices.html#5-selecting-a-response-based-on-the-request